# how can i fix this error of unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', {
    name : {
        type: String,
        required: true//optional
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate (value){
            if(!validator.isEmail(value)){
                throw new Error('Age must be positve number')
            }
        }
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        //custom validator
        validate(value) {
            if (value < 0) {
                throw new Error('Age must be positve number')
            }
        }
    }
})

const me = new User({
    name: 'Killua',
    email: 'mike@'
    
})
me.save().then(() => {
    console.log(me)
}).catch(() => {
    console.log('Error', error)
})
```

showing error-> when using validate showing this error

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: error is not defined
at C:\Users\kbd\Desktop\node\task-manager\src\db\mongoose.js:71:26
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:14088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).

Comment: You've used `error` in the `catch` block's log statement, however, you didn't pass it as a param. Should've been `catch(error => {})`

Comment: ohhhhhh i missed it!! thnx bro

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using create() function.

```
   User.create(
    {
      name: 'Killua',
      email: 'mike@'
    },
    function (err, newuser) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(newuser);
        //do somethinng
      }
    }
  );
```

This is how I normally add an item in mongoose. Please let me know if there are any issues with this method.